Is there a mathematical concept that could serve as an "anti-zero", representing an absolute maximum or the complete counterpart to zero?
I’ve been thinking about the concept of zero in mathematics, particularly its role as the absolute absence of quantity (or as a global minimum, in a sense).
Edited: In my limited mathematical understanding, zero represents nothingness (of quantity, for example).
This got me wondering: If zero represents the absolute absence of values, could there be a counterpart that represents the absolute presence of all values?
I’m imagining a concept that would act as an "anti-zero" — something akin to a global absolute maximum, which encapsulates the totality of all possible values at once. I’m not referring to traditional infinities (such as ∞+ or ∞-, countable ∞ ℵ0, or uncountable ∞ ℵ1, or hyperreal ∞, etc.). Instead, I’m envisioning something more abstract: a value or entity that exists as the opposite of zero, representing absolute completeness.
Added: For me, there is one critical property of the 'anti-zero' that should be mentioned: the 'anti-zero' represents the concept of the largest possible value, like the limit of infinite growth. If we can imagine the absolute absence in mathematics (such as zero or the empty set, if applicable), then perhaps we can also try to imagine its opposite.
Some questions I have:

Does modern mathematics have any concept that resembles this
“anti-zero”?
Is there any formal framework (perhaps in set theory, category
theory, or elsewhere) that could model the idea of an entity that
embodies “the presence of everything”?
Could this idea be a useful abstraction or perhaps lead to a new
kind of mathematical structure or symmetry?

I’d love to hear your thoughts or any references to existing concepts that might align with this idea!

"Zero represents nothingness." If you say so. I think the empty set represents nothingness, and zero is a numeric value.

Dear @Thomas, thank you for your remark/clarification! I admit I’m not a mathematician and don’t have formal mathematical education, but I’m still very curious about the concept of zero and its counterpart. I’d love to explore both perspectives—the numeric value side and the empty set side. It would be fascinating to learn more about each of them.

Can you go into more detail about how the concept you're imagining differs from $+ \infty$, from the extended real line? I would say that $+ \infty$ represents "absolute completeness" or "the largest possible value" pretty well.

By the way, it's important to note that mathematical objects don't inherently "represent," "encapsulate," or "embody" anything; they merely exist and have particular relationships to each other, and then it's up to us to decide what we want to represent by using them. We could use the number 6 to represent "absolute completeness" if we wanted to (but that would be kind of silly).

Dear Sophie, sure, let me try. First, let's think from a different angle: what our mathematical calculation/thinking might be like if we, as humanity, hadn't invented zero and didn't know how to work with a "void" number, which is also a neutral element of addiction (and N and ∅). Instead, we would first invent infinitesimals and infinite hyperreals (already knowing naturals, positive real numbers, etc.). Then we would probably avoid the typical problems/paradoxes of using zero, because we would be working with some values. Then maybe our calculations would be a little bit more understandable.

Part 2/3: But once we have invented and decided to include a concept of numerical "emptiness" (sorry if I use bad terminology), then it can be considered the beginning of a new era of creating the boundaries/limits of the number line (please do not consider negative and complex numbers here for now). And once we have decided to use the concept of minimum (emptiness), then let us introduce the concept of maximum (completeness), which will serve as another limit, but from the other side.

Part 3/3: Here is how I imagine it from a physical point of view. Let us imagine that our universe is the only such entity in existence, and it has some boundaries of extension/enlargement/size. Then the absence of any element/energy/matter/value in this universe can be considered as 0 (complete absence of values), then the presence of maximum element/energy/matter quantity in this universe can be considered as anti-zero (complete presence of values). Anti-zero in this sense would mean that the universe has reached its complete density and there is no other entity that can be added to this uni

Since you've already accepted an answer, I see little point in writing up a new answer that gives you a big list of concepts/references, but for nearly all of the ideas in your post and your comments here, there is at least one already-existing mathematical concept that is similar. Unfortunately, they're almost all separate from each other, so a singular concept that does everything you want likely doesn't exist.

Your recent edit tried to advertise a question (making this question worse) that 1. people can't answer because it has been closed twice for lack of clarity and 2. will likely soon be deleted since you have not edited it to fix the issues that caused it to be closed. I strongly recommend you undo the edit you just made to this question, review How to ask a good question., and then either edit or delete your other question.

Hmm, thanks for your concern. I'll try to edit this question again. It would be a pity if this question also gets closed due to the strict moderation policy of these mathematical forums.

Modern mathematics starts from axioms, not concepts. We don't define $0$ as 'the number representing nothingness' or some such. We define it as a particular set in our set theory (usually the empty set). 'Representation' is too fuzzy an idea to do rigorous mathematics with.
We might still interpret some object that we've defined, or some theorem. For example, we might interpret the set of real numbers $[0, 3]$ as modelling a ladder 3m long, or we might interpret something limiting to $+\infty$ as 'getting infinitely large over time'. But we have to have the actual mathematical object or theorem in order to be able to interpret them.
That doesn't mean the interpretation comes after the rigorous maths historically. For example, mathematicians developed rigorous ways of working with infinitesimals centuries after they started doing calculus. And mathematical ideas are often inspired by real world things, like differential equations being created to model how the universe evolves over time, and some rigorous proofs of Euler's formula being inspired by the intuitive idea of taking a polyhedron, removing a face, and then smushing it flat.
But whilst mathematical objects can be inspired by more vague things, you can't just name a thing and ask for a rigorously defined mathematical object associated with it. Mathematical objects can be interpreted differently in different contexts. When thinking about addition 0 represents leaving everything where it is, but when thinking about multiplication, 1 represents leaving everything where it is and 0 represents collapsing everything to a point. So it isn't possible to say what represents without being much more precise.

Dear Zoe, thank you for the answer. I agree with you, and I wish I had much more mathematical knowledge, better intelligence and better articulation. But being just a mathematical dilettante, the only thing that I want to raise - is my feeling/thinking that there is probably something wrong with disbalance in having concept of "zero" and not having "anti-zero", and the absence of clear explanation in school and technical institute textbooks why we do not have a proper opposition of zero (which I did not have/read some years ago). That is why I asked for help here - I dont know who can help me

@IhorI. We have many anti-zeros in many different systems. We have $\infty$ in the extended complex plane. We have $1/0$ in wheels, which are a kind of algebraic structure where division by $0$ is possible. But what the 'opposition' of a number is depends on context. Is the opposite of $3$ $1/3$ or $-3$? $0$ is its own additive opposition (we say inverse) and $0$ cannot have a multiplicative inverse, $a$, while numbers still work the way we expect, because
$$a \cdot (0 + 1) = a$$
$$a \cdot 0 + a \cdot 1 = a$$
$$a + 1 = a$$
$$1 = 0$$
So to add an inverse of $0$ you must remove something.

@IhorI. e.g. you could remove the distributive property, so that this argument (which depends on the distributive property) wouldn't hold. But this argument explains why you can't normally have a multiplicative inverse of $0$.

oh, that is very interesting point... Big thanks, now I better see that I have no working idea (I have done imaginary tests/calculations and they all failed) and this is extremely complex field of work (I mean to balance everything and remove all paradoxes in mathematics in general, and solve anti-zero conception problem in particular). I just hope that humanity and/or AGI will somehow solve it in the future.

@I.I. "remove all paradoxes..." There are no known current paradoxes in mathematics to remove. Work done in Proof Assistants like Lean's mathlib library and the Metamath Proof Explorer are growing the amount of mathematics that is basically as confirmed as possible, and have not run into a paradox yet. If you start from the false assumption that there are known paradoxes that need removing, you put yourself against nearly all mathematicians.

Wait-wait-wait. Did you read Henrik Rueping's answer about Russell's paradox? Basic googling shows me at least one more - Cramer-Euler paradox. I tell you more, here is a Wikipedia link to mathematical paradoxes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematical_paradoxes. Are they all solved? If so, why do they remain in literature as "paradoxes" and not as "solved paradoxes"? What am I missing?

@I.I. I don't think 'solved paradox' is a category that anything is classified as. Russell's paradox is not a paradox in modern mathematics (I'll talk specifically about ZF) because 'the set of all sets' doesn't exist in ZF. These paradoxes will all be avoided in ZF somehow or another. But that doesn't mean the paradoxes aren't still philosophically interesting, and a different set theory might avoid a paradox in a different way.

@I.I. There are two types of "paradoxes" in mathematics. There are "true paradoxes", where some assumptions that seem innocuous lead to a contradiction; and there are "apparent paradoxes", which are statements that you would think are false or contradictory are actually true and not contradictory. The Cramer-uler paradox is an "apparent paradox": there is no contradiction, it just seems like there should be one.

@ Zoe & Nicholas - understood, thanks a lot

@ZoeAllen - Thank you for your answers and contributions. I marked your main answer as the 'solution' before my follow-up question about the 'concept of the finality of infinite increase' was unfairly downvoted and closed. As a result, I must leave this topic unresolved until a new Georg Cantor or some GPT-∞ (a Superintelligent AGI) can address not only this 'anti-zero' challenge but also, hopefully in a relatively short time span, all of today's and future mathematical challenges.

And with that, hopefully, mathematicians can finally embrace their true calling: transforming themselves into full-fledged philosophers - decked out in tweed jackets, immersed in endless debates, and boldly pondering the phrase "What if..." without flinching at the concept of absolute infinity/completeness.

@I.I. There is no 'anti-zero challenge'. There are several notions of 'anti-zero' which work perfectly well for what they are used for, and once you get far enough in maths you realise there isn't one unified 'true' number system, you just include or exclude whatever makes your proof work. I think you have some misconceptions about what research mathematicians do, as well as about artificial intelligence.

@ZoeAllen Okay, I easily admit that I can have a lot of misconceptions and that I can have too low intelligence to be able to talk about these math/ai topics, no problem and no hard feelings. But. You might also be so kind as to give me at least one "official" notion of "anti-zero" that has one of its (a.-z.'s) theoretical critical properties (according to my vision): 1) global "anti-zero" - contains the absolute largest possible quantity/value, 2) local "anti-zero" - contains finality of its infinite increase (upper boundary/limit of the specific concept, of infinity for example or other).

@I.I. It's not a matter of intelligence- everyone starts somewhere- it's just a matter of recognising when you don't know something and not trying to speak about them as if you're confident about the answer. I'm afraid I can't answer your question because those are still vague English descriptions which don't have a clear translation into any mathematical concepts.

@I.I. If you want to learn more about this I highly recommend trying to learn axiomatic set theory. You'll get a sense of what can and can't be turned into rigorous mathematics, and you'll see how you can translate what you're thinking of into something rigorous.  As you go along you'll also see in a lot more detail how mathematicians work with various kinds of infinity, which will probably answer what you're wondering, even if you don't know how to express it in a way that is understandable to others right now. There's probably a MSE question about how to start with axiomatic set theory.

@ZoeAllen Thank you for your time and effort. I tried to upvote your answer and others (as well), but the system does not allow it due to lack of reputation points. And thanks for the advice, but I am definitely more focused now on surviving and then thriving financially, so math. self-ed. is kind of a luxury for me now. And let's see - maybe I'll be lucky enough to find the math expert for whom my vague English descriptions will be enough to give me the holistic/definitive answer to the anti-zero situation in Modern Mathmatics. GL & HF!

In fact $0$ is just a number. It represents a number of things:

the neutral element for the addition
the minimum element of the ordinals (${\Bbb N}$)
the cardinal of the empty set ($\emptyset$)

The absolute nothingness would be better represented by the empty set.
Unfortunately it is hard to imagine a mathematical object being the opposite:

it has been proven for some time that the set of all sets cannot exist (more exactly it cannot respect the axioms defining what a set is)
by definition the ordinals have no maximum element

The infinites ($\infty$ and $-\infty$) could be the closest thing to the opposite of $0$ when you considere the real numbers set (${\Bbb R}$). For example when studying the topology of (${\Bbb R}$) it is common to considere the set $\overline{\Bbb R} = {\Bbb R} \cup\{-\infty, \infty\}$ to have a compact set. We can even extend the addition to make the infinities become absorbant elements, except that doing so:

we lose the group property
we get a number of undetermined operation: $0\times \pm\infty, \infty-\infty$ (maybe others I cannot think of now)

But it is only the opposite of one single aspect of what $0$ is, in one single point of view...

Dear Serge, thanks a lot for the answer! Would it not be too ignorant or impossible a thing to change our approach from considering anti-zero as the set of all sets to a set of one element, which is the largest possible value? I mean, if zero is the cardinality of the empty set, can we think of anti-zero as the cardinality of the 1-element set? But that 1-element will be the largest possible number that is considered to be the opposite of zero.

@I.I. The content of a set does not matter. The cardinality of a one-element set is $1$. It doesn't matter what that one element is. Furthermore, mathematics is usually axiomatized as a set theory where the only objects are sets. For example, if ${}$ is the empty set then typical definitions for natural numbers are $$0={},\quad1={{}},\quad2={{},{{}}},\quad3={{},{{}},{{},{{}}}}$$ and so on. We can build rational numbers as sets, real numbers as sets, everything as sets. There are absolutely no "special elements" in this framework.

Not anymore.
The basic issue is Russells paradox. Informally it says that if a Barbier shaves everybody, who doesn't shave himself/herself, does the Barbier shave himself or not. Both yes and no lead to contradictions.
This formulation seems to be not so serious, until mathematicians realized that it can be formalized as :
Let $X:=\{x\mid x\notin x\}$. Is $X\in X$?
Both choices lead to a contradiction. So now we have proven that mathematics contains a contradiction and thus all proofs are completely worthless.
Of course not really. It just means that we need to make more precise how we can define sets such that a 'definition' as above is not possible anymore.
In Zermelo-Fraenkel the Axiom schema of specification disallows the notation $\{x\mid...\}$. You can only define a set as the all the elements of an already defined set, that satisfy such a relation. For example, if $Y$ is a given set then
$X:=\{x\in Y\mid x\notin x\}$. This would be a valid definition of a set and we do not obtain a contration anymore. In one of the cases we then simply conclude that $X\notin Y$ and that is it.
And this is the basic problem with a set $All$ containing all sets. If such a thing existed, we would again be in trouble by defining $X:=\{x\in All\mid x\notin x\}$. We would then run into a contradiction again, since we can now conclude $X\notin All$ and by definition of all, we again end up with a contradiction and so all math is again incorrect.
Thus in the world of Zermelo-Fraenkel set-theory there cannot be such a set of all sets.
However, there aref other choices to forbit something so that $\{x\mid x\in x\}$ cannot be defined. For example there is new foundations which has a set of all sets, but which allows restriction only along special (so called 'stratified') formulas. The definition of stratified is made exactly in a way, so that $x\notin x$ cannot be used.
It is just th case that today most mathematicians work with Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory.
That being said, in many context, say when thinking about real numbers it is totally fine to consider the set of all real numbers and work with it.

Dear Henrik, thank you very much for your answer! Is it possible to reframe the problem by considering the opposite (or mirror) of the empty set concept? Instead of working with the set of all sets, what if we consider a set that contains all possible values, starting from the smallest non-zero value that comes after zero, up to the largest possible value?
I am referring to the idea of working with a number line with clear boundaries on both sides, such as [0, Number before Anti-Zero]. Maybe this approach could help avoid some of the paradoxes (or I again misunderstood something)

@IhorI. (1) That seems no different from adding $\pm\infty$ to the real number line.

@IhorI. (2) You don't seem to understand how large the set of all sets would be. It contains way more than just all numbers. We can formalize the notion of "size of a set" with cardinality. The set of real numbers has a fixed cardinality, often denoted $2^{\aleph_0}$, which is the cardinality of the set of all subsets of the naturals ${0,1,2,3,\dotsc}$. There are infinitely many cardinalities greater than $2^{\aleph_0}$. The set of all sets (if it could exist) would be larger than all of them.

Dear Nicholas, thank you for the answer. Indeed, I have limited understanding and I definitely need help from knowledgeable/intelligent enthusiasts/experts in mathematics. I am just trying to understand/find a concept opposite to zero that would hopefully fix this imbalance with the zero/anti-zero relationship. It seems to me that almost all concepts (limits, infinities, etc.) have their proper/clear explanations, except zero, its antipode, and their relationship.

"anti-zero" ,  good thinking.
maybe zero has something inside it, which human not yet recognize. Just like many years ago the square (negative 2).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
